# Make first child route active based on current list of available routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Suppose I have the following Routing structure in my Angular app:

```
children: [
    {
        component: Access,
        path: 'access'
    },
    {
        component: Authentication,
        path: 'authentication'
    },
    {
        component: Domains,
        path: 'domains'
    },
    {
        component: Recovery,
        path: 'recovery'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'authentication'
    }
]
```

With the above implementation, because we default to the `authentication` path, this will always be the one that is currently selected. However, I have different users that have different access policies in my application and some cannot access the `authentication` route. In this case, the first route they should be presented with is the `access` route.

Is it possible to instead of hardcoding this `authentication` path as the default one, to select the first one in the list that is available?

*Full Admin*

Authentication => Access => Domains => Recovery

*Custom Admin*

Access => Domains => Recovery

I want `Access` to be the first selected (active) one since it is the first one available in the list of children.

Maybe a custom resolver or guard to decide whether or not, at run-time, said user is `Full` or `Custom` and decide from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a prefect use-case for a routing-guard. Check for example here how to implement one:

https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

In short:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['access']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

and in your routes:

```
import { 
  AuthGuardService as AuthGuard 
} from './auth/auth-guard.service';
// ...
{
    component: Authentication,
    path: 'authentication',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```